# How to include two static libraries that are almost the same for iOS

Tags: ios, static-libraries

I have one static library for testing and one for release.  The debugging static lib has calls that aren't available in the release version.  In my code I use preprocessor macro to guard around calls that are available in the testing static lib.

How do I include both libs in the project and make one of them be linked during the linking process depending on the build I am doing?

NOTE: I don't have access to the code to the static library so I can't make any changes.  All I have access to is the client code making use of the lib.

Comment: Consider using multiple "targets".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `Target Build Settings`, under `Linking`, `Other Link Flags` - you can include your debugging library in `Debug`, and the real one in `Release` (Deployment, etc). First remove it from the `Link Binary With Libraries` under `Build Phases`.

Comment: Should the lib be specified in Build Phases as optional?

Comment: No - remove it completely - since you can only have one there not two. Its the same thing to the build system - libraries in the Build Phase just get added to the link phase. So doing this yourself works fine (I've done this before), but don't have the exact link syntax handy. Will be something like "-l $(XcodeMacroToProjectDirectory)/somefolder/libA.a"

Comment: Is it possible to have the linker not linked a specific library?

Comment: I'm totally confused. You said you have two libraries, one you want for Release, one for Debugging. If you don't link the library how will your app run??? The whole way this technique I laid out for you works, is that you can specify under the Linker Flags different values for each Build Configuration.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  I have quite a few configurations, so I was thinking to do this in an opposite way - have Xcode link by default (in Build Phases) and only in debug configuration I have Xcode unlink the release library and link the debugging library.  Probably doesn't work that way.

Comment: So don't edit all the Targets, copy and paste in the Project build setting - make every config default to the standard library. Its possible if you just paste this in with the disclosure triangle closed it will apply to all configurations. Then change just the ones for debug. But I know of no way to have a library in the Link Phase and then "undo" that one. Get the right string for the regular library, don't worry about he debug one til you get it all working with one library.